# Visual Studio 2015 RC Community Expired

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I 've downloaded the visual studio 2015 community , on the Microsoft website says it's FREE only have a Microsoft account ( outlook) but after 30 days the account has expired.
I tried to search some of them would be several solutions ( reinstall or repair visual) I already did these two options I tried to find some answer , most could not.
[image]

Comment: You're using the release candidate. Download the actual version.

Comment: As it says, "The prerelease has expired. Thank you for your participation. Upgrade to the latest version of this product to keep working without interruption." What happens when you click "Upgrade your prerelease"?

Comment: "Downloaded license is insufficient" Strange as it downloaded and executable ( vscomunnity ) has the same size than downloaded 30 days ago, I downloaded and am installing again (https://www.visualstudio.com/products/free-developer-offers-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the RC version. Download and install the actual version will resolve this issue. You can download it from this link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146